# Cryptography - Encryption Caesar Cipher Alike Question

Tags: cryptography, pi, caesar-cipher

I have been given the following question.
Decrypt the following message: qtgxuxci,1913.
The hints are the given number have the relationship first 50000 decimal numbers of Pi and the first two char are hk.
It is also known that the mechanism of the encryption is like a Caesar cipher; but each characters is shifted by a different amount.

Here is plain text and encrypted text with number using the machine encrypt:

Every time the result is different:

hongkong : hswoswwp,8857
hongkong : kxslltuk,13828
hongkong : nxpjnovj,24017

waterloo : xfbfvtop,4737
waterloo : jqwonrnn,12868
waterloo : iptknwqi,23114

I do not know what the number mean. At the first thought, I thought it is related to the place of the number in PI. And the place of following digit is the shift number But After I have tried out the above result and the above assumption is not correct. Then, I tried the second is the addition/subtraction.

e.g.
hong kong - hswo swwp (8857), appear in 0478, shift 0, 4, 9, 8, 8,

But it seems not correct too.

Could you provide problem solving ideas and solutions to the above problem? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Caesar cipher. Running down the alphabet gives:

```
qtgxuxci
ruhyvydj
svizwzek
twjaxafl
uxkbybgm
vylczchn
wzmdadio
xanebejp
ybofcfkq
zcpgdglr
adqhehms
berifint
cfsjgjou
dgtkhkpv
ehulilqw
fivmjmrx
gjwnknsy
hkxolotz
ilypmpua
jmzqnqvb
knarorwc
lobspsxd
mpctqtye
nqduruzf
orevsvag
psfwtwbh
```

You need to try a different cipher.

Comment: I know it is not caesar cipher. But I do not know what cipher is used and I do know the answer. The hint is related to pi and it should be a meaningful word somthing like "hkctflag" but the answer is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried shifts of 31415926... ?